# ASP.NET Core 2 TagHelper code not executing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have the following TagHelper

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

namespace Encore.TagHelpers
{
    public class EmailTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.TagName = "a";    // Replaces <email> with <a> tag
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following _ViewImports.cshtml file located directly in the Views folder

```
@using Encore
@using Encore.Models
@using Encore.Models.AccountViewModels
@using Encore.Models.ManageViewModels
@using Encore.Models.SignUpViewModels
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, Encore
```

I've put the tag in a View: `<email>Support</email>`

The code for the email TagHelper never gets executed.

Comment: What is your actual project name where the tag helper is defined? It's it just `Encore.csproj`?

Comment: That is correct. It is Encore.csproj

Comment: Everything from your question looks correct. Have you tried creating the simplest project possible and still reproduce the issue?

Comment: I have.  When I start a project from scratch, it all works.  So I have no idea how things have gone awry with this project.